# MS Office 2019 crashes on Big Sur on startup

Tags: ms-office, crash, big-sur

When I start an app from Microsoft Office 2019 (Word, Excel or Powerpoint) I get the following crash:

```
Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSFileManager createDirectoryAtURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:]: URL is nil'
abort() called
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

- [Full crash log](https://gist.github.com/bilke/866732031ea6c03d52c9b3c8813c0d40)

I tried re-installing Office, deleting the library folder (e.g. `~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Word`). I also get the same error when installing Office 2016!

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you try with another user account (create one if needed)?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! It works as a different user! What can I do now as my original user?

Comment: Look in your ~/Library folder and delete everything that has "microsoft" or "office" in the file name. There will be folders and files in that folder, ~/Library/Application Support and ~/Library/Preferences and ~/Library/Preferences/Cache. Note that if you have templates or email saved in Office doing this will delete your settings, templates, locally saved mail, etc.

Comment: I would start with removing the *.autoSave files/directories, sometimes that's enough to get it fixed.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, now it works on my user account. I do not know what fixed it but last delete command I ran in `~/Library` was `rm -r Group\ Containers/UBF8T346G9.ms Application\ Scripts/com.microsoft*`. Thanks!!